# hive/hdfs moving data not working as expected

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, partitioning

I had a table in hive called as test at location say **'hdfs://location1/partition='x''** and moved all the data to **'hdfs://location2/partition='x''**.

```
hdfs dfs -mv /location1 /location2
```

Then I did

```
alter table test set location 'hdfs://location2'.
```

On doing

```
 hdfs dfs -ls /location2
```

I see all the data in the right partition

Querying to get counts i.e.

```
select count(*) from test
```

works fine.

But doing

```
 select * from test
```

pulls no records.

Unable to figure what went wrong while moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop the existing partitions that was pointing to the original location "hdfs://location1/partition='x'" manually.
 Use below command to drop all the partitions manually:

```
alter table test drop partition(partition='x');
```

Once all the partitions are dropped run the below command to update the new partitions in hive metastore:

```
msck repair table test;
```

Why this? Because since the location of table was changed but the hive metastore was not updated with the new partitions in new location. The hive metastore is still holding the information about the partitions from old location. Once you drop partition and run the

> msck repair

command, the hive metastore will get updated with the new partitions from new location.